# How do I make excel label every bar in a bar chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a pivot table of names (1st column) and corresponding data (2nd column). I want to create a bar chart that places a label on *every* bar, regardless of whether excel thinks it will fit or not.

Here is what I have done:

1. Insert->Pivot Chart
2. Click `Clustered Column`
3. Right-click on graph, select `Format Axis`
4. set `specify unit interval` to 1

Excel now just labels every 2nd bar, even though it would easily fit (I have about 150 bars) with the given label font size. Even though I have selected 1, it has the same text density as if I set `specify unit interval` to 2.

How do I force it to 1?

Comment: What happens if you change the size of the chart?

Comment: @guitarthrower no effect as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried, and got the same thing. So I tried reducing the number of bars to see if there was a limit. I reduced the number of bars to 100 and all the labels show up. Added one more, and they only show every other label.

I also tried with a normal chart (not a pivot chart) and got the same results. 100 labels = OK. 101 = No Go.

It appears you have found a limitation in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but simply changing the size of the chart worked, just put the Arrow icon on the top right hand corner and dreagged it bigger.  It also worked if I changed the font size of my labels but then the print was too small to be useful for my intentions.